# linux custom list directory

Tags: linux, ls

I know it's a dumb question: how can I ls some directory (files+directory inside) and return something like : 0 for files, 1 for directory, 2 for simlink

```
<name_dir>,1
<name_dir>,1
<name_file>,0
<name_file>,0
<name_file>,0
<name_file>,0
```

I need to pass the result over ssh and I think to have as small as possible traffic.
Maybe this isn't the smartest option, any idea? ls or find -printf

Comment: I would write a custom ls program in c, using the stat systemcall. see [man stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -F` marks directories with a trailing slash. Then use `sed` to convert the slash into ",1" and to get rid of the other marks (for symlinks etc) or replace them by a suffix of your choice. Finally append ",0" to everything which does not end in ",1" (or any other suffix you added)

This suffixes directories with ",1" and everything else with ",0"

```
ls -F | sed '
   s/[\*\@\|]$//;
   s/=>$//;
   s/\/$/,1/;
   /,1$/! s/$/,0/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in `ls -1 --group-directories-first`; do
    if [ -d $f ]; then echo "$f,1";
    elif [ -L $f ]; then echo "$f,2";
    else echo "$f,0"; fi
done
```